# How to get rid off underscore "_" from the rails generated url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I just implemented **friendly_id** on the category model of rails app. Earlier it used to generate url like this:

`localhost/search?category_id=208`. Now I got it to generate url as below

```
localhost:3000/search?category_id=metal-processing-and-machine-tool
```

The url generating line is:

```
<a href="<%= search_equipments_path(:category_id => category.slug ) %>">
```

The `search_equipments` method is as follows:

```
def search_equipments
    begin
      if (params.keys & ['category_id', 'sub_category', 'manufacturer', 'country', 'state', 'keyword']).present?
        if params[:category_id].present?
          @category = Category.active.find params[:category_id]
        else
          @category = Category.active.find params[:sub_category] if params[:sub_category].present?
        end
        @root_categories = Category.active.roots
        @sub_categories = @category.children.active if params[:category_id].present?
        @sub_categories ||= {}
        @countries = Country.active.all
        @manufacturers = Manufacturer.active.all
        @states = State.active.where("country_id = ?", params[:country]) if params[:country].present?
        @states ||= {} 
        unless params[:category_id].present? && params[:sub_category].present?
          params[:category_id] = @category.id if params[:category_id].present?
          params[:sub_category] = @category.id if params[:sub_category].present?
        end   
        @equipments = Equipment.active.filter(params.slice(:manufacturer, :country, :state, :category_id, :sub_category, :keyword)).order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}, created_at desc")             
      else
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Something went wrong!"
    end
 end
```

Because of SEO reasons the people above me are telling to get rid off the `_` which is in `category_id` from the url. I tried by changing the format in url generating line. Didn't help. Can please anyone tell me if  it is doable and how can I achieve that?

Please let me know in the comments if any extra information needed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just change `<a href="<%= search_equipments_path(:category_id => category.slug ) %>">` to `<a href="<%= search_equipments_path(:categoryid => category.slug ) %>">` which will set the `params[:categoryid]`. You will then need to modify all of your checks to `if params[:categoryid].present?` etc. Then when you click on the link it should goto `localhost:3000/search?categoryid=`

Comment: I thought about it and already tried it but didn't work. But since you also mentioned the same thing let me try it once again.

Comment: On console it changed. `Parameters: {"categoryid"=>"metal-processing-and-machine-tool"}`. But didn't generate the url as expected.

Comment: When I clicked on the link it remained on the same page.

Comment: What are your routes like? This should work by changing to categoryid, unless you're doing something with your routes.

Comment: route `  get "/search" => 'welcome#search_equipments', as: :search_equipments`

Comment: I don't see why changing the parameter wouldn't work then. Why doesn't that work for you?

Comment: I don't know. When changed everything to `categoryid` in controller and in href and clicked on the link it went  to  this line in the method `rescue Exception => e
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Something went wrong!"
    end` and flashed  **Something went wrong** on the  browser.

Comment: I commented that exception and changed everything to `categoryid` . Now I got a mysql error. `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'equipment.categoryid' `

Comment: You've changed to much then :) Only change the things that are in the params, you probably don't want to change the db column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142167/discussion-between-user3576036-and-iceman).